# Calculating sum of all numbers in a line and printing the output to a separate file

Tags: unix, math, awk, while-loop

I would like to calculate the sum of all the numbers in a line from a text file and print the output including the numbers and the sum of each line to a separate file.

The input.txt:
input.txt

```
5S_rRNA 0       0       44      44      1       7
7SK     0       0       44      43      2       4
A1BG    0       0       0       0       0       0
ABCA9.AS1       0       0       0       0       0       0
ABCB1   0       0       1       0       0       0
```

output.txt

```
5S_rRNA 0   0   44  44  1   7   96
7SK 0   0   44  43  2   4   93
A1BG    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
ABCA9.AS1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
ABCB1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
```

I have tried:

```
while read x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7
        do
                x=$((x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7))
        echo $x
done < input.txt > output.txt
```

but I get this error message: test_sum.sh: Illegal number: 5S_rRNA
I have also tried

```
awk '$2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7 {print $0}' input.txt > output.txt
```

but I get a load of 0 and 1's.

Any suggestions would be brilliant.
Thanks, 
Harriet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
$ awk '{print $0,$2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7}' file
5S_rRNA 0       0       44      44      1       7 96
7SK     0       0       44      43      2       4 93
A1BG    0       0       0       0       0       0 0
ABCA9.AS1       0       0       0       0       0       0 0
ABCB1   0       0       1       0       0       0 1
```

In your case,

```
awk '{print $0,$2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
5S_rRNA 0       0       44      44      1       7
```

For a line that looks like the above, the problem in your script is here:

```
while read x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7
      #7 items to read, you are using 6 variables.
```

The above is exactly the reason why you are getting `Illegal number: 5S_rRNA`

Change that to:

```
while read x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 
      # Add the last 6 items as you are doing.
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same comment

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tricky bash way:

```
while read -a words; do
    echo "${words[@]}" $(IFS=+; echo "${words[*]:1}" | bc)
done < input.txt > output.txt
column -t output.txt
```

```
5S_rRNA    0  0  44  44  1  7  96
7SK        0  0  44  43  2  4  93
A1BG       0  0  0   0   0  0  0
ABCA9.AS1  0  0  0   0   0  0  0
ABCB1      0  0  1   0   0  0  1
```